# java hibernate runtime exception

Tags: hibernate, object-persistence, hibernateexception

I'm trying to use Java Hibernate. I tried to run the **HelloWorld** example from http://www.manning.com/bauer2/chapter2.pdf. But I have run into some trouble. The jar version I'm using is not the same as in the book. So, I have to get rid of the deprecated way of instantiating `SessionFactory`. The **ant compile** is successful but as you can see, when I **ant run**, I get the following exception.

> C:\_Java Hibernate>ant run 
> Buildfile: C:\_Java Hibernate\build.xml
>
> clean:
>    [delete] Deleting directory
>  C:\_Java Hibernate\bin
>     [mkdir] Created dir: C:\_Java Hibernate\bin 
>
> compile:
>     [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\_Java Hibernate\bin
>
> copymetafiles:
>      [copy] Copying 3 files to C:\_Java Hibernate\bin
>
> run:
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  
>      [java] INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>      [java] INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.1}
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>      [java] INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeP
> rovider
>      [java] INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure 
>      [java] INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml 
>      [java] Mar 31, 2012 3:09:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigura 
> tionInputStream
>      [java] INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>      [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>      [java]     at persistence.HibernateUtil.(Unknown Source) 
>      [java]     at hello.HelloWorld.main(Unknown Source) 
>      [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configu
> ration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>      [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.jav
> a:2013) 
>      [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:
> 1925) 
>      [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:
> 1904)   
>      [java]     ... 2 more
>      [java] Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: http://hibernate.org/hiberna
> te-configuration-3.0.dtd Nested exception: http://hibernate.org/hibernate-config
> uration-3.0.dtd
>      [java]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484) 
>      [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.jav
> a:2005) 
>      [java]     ... 4 more
>      [java] Java Result: 1
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
> Total time: 2 seconds

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception may be there is configuration problem. First you use netbeans and then create java application with hibernate framework. Then may be true generated config file by netbeans usefull to solve out your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your rply rajc242. I used netbeans as you suggested to no avail. I got the same error.

Comment: Then if possible then send me your config file to my mail id. I will check that and give you ans as fast as possible. My mail id is rajc242@gmail.com